# Invalid scope trying get authorization token for Gmail SMTP access

Tags: email, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-oauth

I'm trying out my new SMTP library and trying to use it to send mail via Gmail. To do that, I need an OAuth2 access token. I've set up an OAuth2 client account in the Google API console, enabled the Gmail API and added the `https://mail.google.com/` scope in the OAuth consent screen setup. Despite this, the POST request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code returns the error 
`invalid_scope`. Switching the scope to `email` makes the request go through. I tried two different HTTP clients to be sure this wasn't some freak encoding problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the "device" authorization flow supports only a limited set of scopes, and `https://mail.google.com` is not one of them.